# How to I find the smallest numbers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array containing only numbers and a special character, `E`. The array can contain more than one `E`. My function should return smallest numbers currently in the whole set whenever E is encountered.

```
function OffLineMinimum(strArr) {
    var arr = [],
        len = strArr.length,
        res = [],
        i = 0;
  while (i < len) {
        if (strArr[i] != "E") {
            arr.push(parseInt(strArr[i]));
            i++;
        } else {
        res.push(arr.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        })[0]);
        i = i + 2;
        }
    }
    return res.join(",");
}
console.log(OffLineMinimum(["5", "4", "6", "E", "1", "7", "E", "E", "3", "2"]));
// output: 4,1,5
```

Comment: Awesome! So what's your *question*?

Comment: I understand 4 and 1 ... what is 5?

Comment: when 3rd E encountered numbers so far listed are [5,4,6,1,7] . As 4 and 1 are returned by 2 E's earlier, from [5,6,7] smallest is 5.

Comment: Unable to get output as expected.

Comment: well ... that makes sense ... what would `["5", "4", "6", "E", "8", "7", "E", "E", "3", "2"]` output? 4,7,5 ?

Comment: Yes, it is 4,7,5..

Comment: I think your `i = i + 2;` is the problem - what does your code output now?

Comment: I would've thought `["5", "4", "6", "E", "8", "7", "E", "E", "3", "2"]` would result in 4,5,6 ... 4,7,5 would mean there's logic needed to detect if anything has been "pushed" since the previous number removed, and only use all remaining numbers rather than just the last block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question it seems this is what you want

```js
var t1 = ["5", "4", "6", "E", "1", "7", "E", "E", "3", "2"];
var t2 = ["5", "4", "6", "E", "8", "7", "E", "E", "3", "2"];
function OffLineMinimum(strArr) {
    return strArr.reduce((result, item) => {
        if (item === 'E') {
            result.output.push(result.work.sort((a, b) => a - b).shift());
        } else {
            result.work.push(Number(item));
        }
        return result;
        
    }, {output: [], work: []}).output;
}
console.log(OffLineMinimum(t1).toString());
console.log(OffLineMinimum(t2).toString());
```

However, t2, according to the **comment** should result in 4,7,5

So the logic is not as described at all. But it seems the second `E` in a row uses the remaining full set so far, where as the first only should use the current "block" since the last `E`

Code:

```js
var t1 = ["5", "4", "6", "E", "1", "7", "E", "E", "3", "2"];
var t2 = ["5", "4", "6", "E", "8", "7", "E", "E", "3", "2"];
function OffLineMinimum(strArr) {
    return strArr.reduce((result, item) => {
        if (item === 'E') {
            if (result.lastItem === 'E') {
                result.output.push(result.work.sort((a, b) => a - b).shift());
            } else {
                result.output.push(result.block.sort((a, b) => a - b).shift());
                result.work.push(...result.block);
                result.block = [];
            }
        } else {
            result.block.push(Number(item));
        }
        result.lastItem = item;
        return result;
        
    }, {output: [], work: [], block: [], lastItem: ''}).output;
}
console.log(OffLineMinimum(t1).toString())
console.log(OffLineMinimum(t2).toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach first gets all index of `"E"` in array then loops over that array slicing and filtering main array up to that index, then gets min of that subset

```js
function OffLineMinimum(strArr) {
  // first reduce to get indexing of `E`
  const mins = strArr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    return c === 'E' ? a.concat(i) : a;       
  }, [])
  // second reduce slices and filters numbers up to E index to get min
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    let seq = strArr.slice(0, c).filter(v => v !== 'E' && !a.includes(+v)).map(Number);
    return a.concat(Math.min(...seq))
  }, []);
  return mins.join()
}

let arrs = [{
    expect: '4,1,5',
    arr: ["5", "4", "6", "E", "1", "7", "E", "E", "3", "2"]
  },
  {
    expect: '4,5,6',
    arr: ["5", "4", "6", "E", "8", "7", "E", "E", "3", "2"]
  }
]
arrs.forEach(o => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(o.arr));
  console.log('Expect:', o.expect, 'Result:', OffLineMinimum(o.arr))
});
```